# Vaadin Flow TextField: how dynamically change font color?

Tags: css, vaadin-flow

I want to dynamically change font color of a Vaadin Flow `TextField` component.

Tried this, but does not work:

```
textField.getElement().setProperty("color", "red");
```

I suspect this is because the `<input>` element is hidden in the shadow dom. I have no clue how to handle this.

BTW I am aware of the [Dynamic Styling tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/element-api/tutorial-dynamic-styling.html).

Comment: Have you checked this question and answer?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126339/dynamically-changing-font-font-size-font-color-and-so-on-in-vaadin-flow-web-a/53129202

Comment: I have not yet tested it myself, but I think solution to your problem is to define themable mixin with "input-element" part and use custom property for font color there, which you define in your global styles, and then you can dynamically change value of the custom property.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i have seen that question. I have not seen example code of how to create a themable mixin and custom properties in the Java (Flow) code. A cannot get the complete picture yet. Besides that, is this not an overly complex approach for a rather common and simple use-case?

Comment: There is another question and answer about the same topic, which has an example about text field styling with themable mixin, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141129/vaadin-flow-10-11-style-component-via-css/53151242#53151242

Comment: Thanks Tatu, it is now clear for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Custom Theme feature](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme), you can add your custom theme `@Theme(value = "my-theme")`, create a CSS stylesheet file `${project.basedir}/frontend/themes/my-theme/components/vaadin-text-field.css` and place the following there:

```css
:host(.my-class-red) [part="input-field"]{
    color:red
}

:host(.my-class-blue) [part="input-field"]{
    color:blue
}
```

On the Java side:

```java
TextField name = new TextField("Your name");
name.setLabel("My label");
        
Button red = new Button("Red", click -> {
   name.removeClassName("my-class-blue");
   name.addClassName("my-class-red");
});

Button blue = new Button("Blue", click -> {
   name.removeClassName("my-class-red");
   name.addClassName("my-class-blue");
});

Button reset = new Button("Reset", click -> {
   name.removeClassNames("my-class-red", "my-class-blue");
});

add(red, blue, reset);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! great first contribution, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @rmuller ! I'm glad this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care that the text color of the label above the input field also turns red, you also could use this in combination (tested with Vaadin 14.2.1, in current Firefox and Chromium):

```
textField.getElement().getStyle().set("color", "red");
textField.getElement().getStyle().set("-webkit-text-fill-color", "red");
```